# Нужен способ зашифровать видео на мобильном телефоне

Tags: android, ios, шифрование, видео, mobile-development

Добрый день.

У меня есть следующая задача. Требуется сделать мобильное приложение под android + ios, которое будет грузить с нашего хостинга видео фрагменты для просмотра в оффлайн. Эти фрагменты должны быть доступны только через приложение после аутентификации, просмотреть их "просто так" должно быть не возможно (ну или крайне не тривиально)

Подскажите хотя бы в сторону какой технологии/библиотек копать. Сильно не хочется шифровать все видео - это огромная нагрузка на аккумулятор при воспроизведении.

Спасибо.

Comment: я смотрю это очень популярный подход смотреть видео оффлайн. так все плохо со скоростью интернета?

Answer (score 1):

Шифруйте не все. Шифруйте начало файла, остальное оставляйте как есть и меняйте расширение на свое. Большинство стандартных способов для открытия сразу отпадет.

Либо можете придумать свою логику. К примеру, шифровать каждые `n` байт с шагом в `m` байт.